# assistance with Group Java Project

Tags: java, project

This seems  a lot and I'm sorry if this is bad but I have a group java project that's due soon
it's supposed to be based on anything and my group came up with a 10 question quiz as what we should program
we are having trouble coming up with the right coding can any of you give us a good blueprint or an idea where to start
we have a lot of requirements in our project

the program is required to have
1 Scanner Class
2 Variables,Constants
3 switch statement
4 conditional operator
5 Operators(logical, arithmetical,assignment)
6 String class method
7 Math class method
8 Loop
9 Method passing argument by values
9 Return value from method
10 Method overloading,overriding
11 Array
12 Add multiple classes
13 Extend another class
14 Create an Object
15 Constructor
16 Super Keyword
17 Abstraction
18 Polymorphism
19 Inheritance
20 Encapsulation
21 Exception handling
22 Using Java libarary class such as Date, Random etc
23 Static variable and Static methods
24 using this keyword
25 Modifier
26 Println ,printf methods

Comment: Start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). There are no magical answers. Just work through your exercises one step at a time.

Comment: So you expect us to do your homework for you?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to write a console application.
Ok, you've chozen it to be a quiz. No, do some analysis of the problem. What will be the subject of the quiz? What kinds of questions you'll have? In what form the answers will be given (a number, a selection from a list of options, yes/no, a word etc.)? So, you'll get a set of entities that your app should deal with. These entities will become base classes for your app. The user interface could be quite simple, like printing a question to the console and reading input back.

Gradually working on this task you can master many aspects of OOP.